# anonymous function returning updated length of an array - matlab

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

I'm trying to write a simple anonymous function which returns the length of an array

```
>> a=[1 2 3];

>> f = @() length(a);

>> f()
    3

>> a = [1 2 3 4];

>> f()
    3
```

Is it possible to write a function that returns the length of the updated array every time it's called?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want `a` passed in as an argument?

Comment: You're just calling `length` in your function, so why not just use `length`? If you need a function handle, use `f = @length;`.

Comment: And did you read [this section of the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621)?

Comment: @jodag: "a" can be a nested structure with many sub-fields so it would be convenient to define it just once inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ugly method to accomplish what you want

```
global a;
a = [1 2 3];
f = @() eval('global a; length(a)')
f()
a = [1 2 3 4];
f()
```

I'm compelled to say that I strongly recommend against this type of code as it relies on both globals and calls to `eval`, both of which should be avoided when possible.

A better method would be to pass in `a` as an argument to the function

```
a = [1 2 3];
f = @(x) length(x)
f(a)
a = [1 2 3 4];
f(a)
```

or, because in this case calling `f` is identical to calling `length`, then there's really no reason to use anonymous functions at all.

```
a = [1 2 3];
length(a)
a = [1 2 3 4];
length(a)
```

Comment: Really not worth mentioning the ugly `eval` method, it only encourages bad practise, **don't use `eval` when avoidable**! Defining the function to take an argument is the correct answer, aside from explaining why it was previously failing (because `a` was static within `f` when `f` was defined in terms of `a`)

Comment: It depends on the constraints of the problem. If `a` must not be an argument then using `eval` may not be avoidable. If passing in `a` as an argument is possible then `eval` should not be used.

Comment: If `a` must not be an argument (especially in something this simple), then you've structured your code badly.

Answer (score 3):

Defining an anonymous function in terms of a variable makes that variable static within the function. i.e.

```
% this...
a = [1 2 3];
f = @() length(a);
% ...  is equivalent to this...
f = @() length([1 2 3]);
```

You want to create an anonymous function which can take an argument

```
f = @(x) length(x);
a = [1 2 3]; 
f(a); % >> ans = 3
a = [1 2 3 4]; 
f(a); % >> ans = 4
```

Although at that point, just use `length(a)` and don't define some pointer-function!